# the output response cannot be obtained in the topic 'express' when the request is sent in visual studio code and in postman

Tags: express, post, response

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbowG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5QMG.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9SD7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtHwd.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4NEb.png)
when the request is sent it just process for long time,but output response of the request hasn't received yet.
i had tried even in postman but still the hasn't sent and the response is not yet received.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should write `app.use(express.json())` in `server.js`.